# Disable taglib scanning in google app engine (Jetty)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, jetty, taglib

Trying to reduce the startup time of my instances I've come accross the taglib classpath scanning.

My application has 50mb of jars. The scanning of the tld takes 20% of the startup time.

[image: Yourkit capture of the startup time]

Is there a way to disable that? I just use JSTL standard libs which are already included ([gae doc for jsp](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#JSPs))

I'd like to disable as well JSP precompilation.

Comment: have you found the answer? the proposed answer doesn't work on appengine.

Comment: What did work for Rafael is renaming his JARs to match the predefined NoTLDJarPattern pattern of AppEngine's default web.xml: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28203683/180740

Answer (score 4):

I looked in the sourcecode of TagLibConfiguration http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jetty/jetty-6.1.26/org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/TagLibConfiguration.java.html#line.134 and found that it respects a parameter NoTLDJarPattern

The NoTLDJarPattern paramter is configured in web.xml to reduce scanning time:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.NoTLDJarPattern</param-name>
    <param-value>test.jar|prefix-.*\.jar</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I'd like to debug that. How can I find which exact version of jetty does gae 1.7.3 use?

Comment: Sorry i got no idea, btw what tool do you use to produce that screenshot?

Comment: this doesn't work for appengine. Are you shure it should work?

Comment: Sorry, i just looked it up in some jetty sources and wrote an answer that got accepted. I never actually tried it :(

Answer (score 1):

See this...

[Jsp Jetty Configuration](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jsp+Configuration)

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily disable precompilation, just put next line in the deployment descriptor web.xml file : [App-Engine doc here.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Disabling_Precompilation)

```
<precompilation-enabled>false</precompilation-enabled>
```

Comment: precompilation should be enabled, that means to compile JSP at deployment time, not at instance init time, and that's what we want